# how to change property with onPressed in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am working on a flutter app and I wanted to change the color property(for each widget) to red when the user clicks on red and to green when the user clicks on the green. So any help?

**this is the code of the widgets of the first page**

```
 cardItem(BuildContext context, int index){
    return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
    child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: ()
                 {
                 SecondPage.name = "Question ${index +1}";
                 SecondPage.index = index;
                 Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:  
                (context) => SecondPage()));
                 },
                 child: Card(
                 color: Colors.white,
                 child: ListTile(
                 title: Text('Question ${index +1 }'),
                 subtitle: Text('Yes or No'),
                     )
                  )

                   )
                  );
                     }
                  }
```

**this is the code of the yes or no page**

```
class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
           @override
         Widget build(BuildContext context){
         return Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(SecondPage.name),
    ),
    body: Center(
      child:
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 3),
            child: FlatButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text('No', style: TextStyle(color:                          Colors.black),),
              onPressed: () {

              },
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 3),
            child: FlatButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Text('Yes', style: TextStyle(color:                         Colors.black),),
              onPressed: () {

              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),


    )
);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a color variable  `Color color;` inside your state and then give this color to all of your widget like button or whatever you have, And when user clicks on red inside the onPressed of your red button.

```
color =Colors.red;
setState(() { });
```

similarly, you can do this inside your green color button.

Comment: Sorry, I am a little beginner. Can you explain in more detail? For your information, when the user presses the Yes button, I want to change the color of the widget for the first question only

Answer (score 0):

1). First declare a global variable like this,

```
 var btnColor = Colors.green;
```

2). Now use this variable inside your widget like this,

```
color: btnColor,
```

3). Now use setState on button pressed to change the value of the Color

```
onPressed: () {
   setState(() { 
   btnColor = Colors.red;
 }); 
},
```

> The value of color will change. This is called Stage-management you can
> learn more about that